# How does the compaction internal is decided in DateTieredCompactionStrategy in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

I came across this Datastax documentation of Cassandra. I couldn't understand [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/compactSubprop.html#compactionSubpropertiesDTCS) it is mentioned `min_threshold` as `The minimum number of SSTables that trigger a minor compaction` where as [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dtcs-notes-from-the-field) it says `it Controls how many intervals of time are combined to create the next larger interval size`. So, how the number of compaction interval and SSTables is connected. Also, I couldn't understand how does the compaction happen in the DateTieredCompactionStrategy. If it is purely decided by `base_time_seconds`. Does it mean oldest SSTable would always participate in compaction till it reaches its age?

Comment: DTCS is pretty confusing and hard to tune, if you switch to TWCS it gets a lot easier. In newer versions of C* TWCS replaced DTCS, to get it in C* 2.0 you will probably need to go to https://github.com/jeffjirsa/twcs and port it, since its only made for 2.1+

Answer (score 0):

Lets understand few things.

**how is data stored** :

> The Cassandra write process stores data in files called SSTables. SSTables are immutable. Instead of overwriting existing rows with inserts or updates, Cassandra writes new timestamped versions of the inserted or updated data in new SSTables. Cassandra does not perform deletes by removing the deleted data: instead, Cassandra marks it with tombstones.

Over time, Cassandra may write many versions of a row in different SSTables. Each version may have a unique set of columns stored, and a different timestamp. This distribution of data could require Cassandra to access more and more SSTables to retrieve a complete row.

> To keep the database healthy, Cassandra periodically merges SSTables and discards old data. This process is called compaction.

Now that we know why compaction happens lets  see how compaction happens?

There are many compaction strategies.
Lets discuss the two which you are confused about

**1. SizeTieredCompactionStrategy (STCS)** 
The SizeTieredCompactionStrategy (STCS) initiates compaction when Cassandra has accumulated a set number (default: 4) of similar-sized SSTables.

> so in this case the **min_threshold** is the minimum number of SSTables that trigger a minor compaction, of similar size. so as soon as you have 4 sstables of same size , compaction will trigger.

**2. DateTieredCompactionStrategy (DTCS)**
The DateTieredCompactionStrategy (DTCS) is similar to STCS. **But instead of compacting based on SSTable size, DTCS compacts based on SSTable age**.

The basic idea of DTCS is to group SSTables in windows based on how old the data is in the SSTable. We then only do compaction within these windows to make sure that we don’t mix new and old data.

The size of the compaction windows is configurable. The **base_time_seconds** option sets the size of the initial window and defaults to 1 hour. This means the data that was written in the last hour will be in that first window, and will be compacted with data from the same window. Any reads that want to read data from the latest hour will only have to look at SSTables that were compacted or flushed in that window. The older windows then get larger and larger, and finally we have max_sstable_age_days which is when we don’t compact the SSTables anymore.

So In case of DateTieredCompactionStrategy the min_threshold is still 4(configurable via min_threshold) sstable but which 4 sstables you will compact varies. So in **STCS** the 4 sstables you will compact are the one with the same size. However in **DTCS** you will choose the 4 which have the same min/max timestamps as the total min/max timestamps of the compacted SSTables.

You can read more about it here http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datetieredcompactionstrategy

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataMaintain.html#stcs-compaction

Comment: That is my doubt. What's the point of `base_time_seconds` if you are only choosing 4 SSTable within that `base_time_seconds` you can have any number of SSTable.  Also, all older SSTables always participate in compaction or not?